# Smooth reload of uitableview data when rows are deleted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to reload a uitableview when it scrolls to the bottom of the screen. I delete the first few rows and add more rows to the bottom. **Before** the news rows are added to the uitableview's data source, i call the `[tableview reloaddata]` method. This is because i want the tableview to display the row which were previously visible on it.

It reloads the data correctly but there is a sudden jerk in the tableview. It flashes which doesn't give a nice user experience. So my question is

1. How to update the uitableview
   when few rows from the top are
   deleted without having the
   jerking/flashing effect?
2. The current visible row should be retained in the refreshed view also.

Any ideas? There are no crashes as i update the data source correctly.

TIA,

Praveen S

Comment: are you deleting using -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: Nope i am just deleting the data from the data source. And i want this to be reflected into my uitableview.

Answer (score 0):

delete the data from the data source in tableView delegate.

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


            NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            NSMutableArray *nameSection =[names objectForKey:key];

            int itemID=item.ID;
            if ([nameSection count]==1) {
                [self.keys removeObjectsInArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:key]];

                [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
            else {
                [nameSection removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [self.names setValue:nameSection forKey:key];

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            }
        }
```

[check this too](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html)

Comment: The thing is i would just know which indexes from the data source array i want to delete, so i think the above solution wouldn't work. The user is not deleting the rows himself.

Comment: if you datasource is array you may know the index of the object removing from array. create index path using this index.  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: I will try this and update here. I may have to screw up my MVC a little here to get the indexes.