# How to delete a custom tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i am using custom cell in uitableview cell.I am giving button on the right of the navigation bar .if user click on the button the delete cell option has to come like default cell delete option...can any one share code ...thanks in advance....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[check this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593089/smooth-reload-of-uitableview-data-when-rows-are-deleted/6593284#6593284)

Answer (score 0):

To delete a `UITableViewCell`, you should remove the data from the Array that populated the tableview. You can remove it using any logic, and the value of the `row` returned from the touch.

After that, a simple `[tableView reloadData];` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click the button corresponding the custom cell you should move the data of the next concurrent cells to their previous cell and then call [reloadData]